# Storing Command Line Arguments in an Array , Arguments can be Integers OR a file containing integers delimited by a space

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, sh

Requirement :

1. Able to send a file containing numbers (433 434 435) as a parameter
   sh Test.sh myFile.txt
2. Parameters can be numbers directly if not a file (433 434 434)
   sh Test.sh 434 435 436

So , it has to support both file and numbers as the parameters

Below is the code i ve tried writing but in the for loop below , all numbers are getting printed as a string , but i need the for loop to run thrice as the input values are 3.
How to have it as a part of an array in shell script

Iam relatively new to shell script

OutPut:

In either case for loop has to run the number of parameter times(filedata determinies the parameters or direct input) 
Please advice if any unforeseen bugs exist

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e $@ 2>&1 ;
myFile=$1 ; // As the first parameter will be a file
#[ -f "$myFile" ] && echo "$myFile Found" || echo "$myFile Not found"
if [ -f "$myFile" ]; then
        tcId=`cat $@`;
        echo $tcId;
else
        tcId=$@;
        echo $tcId;
fi

# Execute each of the given tests
for testCase in "$tcId"
do
     echo "Test Case is "$testCase ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a process substitution to "pretend" the explicit arguments are in a file.

```
while IFS= read -r testCase; do
    echo "Test case is $testCase"
done < <( if [ -f "$1" ]; then
              cat "$1"
          else
              printf "%s\n" "$@"
          fi
        )
```

If you are flexible in how your script is called, I would simplify it to *only* read test cases from standard input

```
while IFS= read -r testCase; do
    echo "Test case is $testCase"
done
```

and call it one of two ways, neither using command line arguments:

```
sh Test.sh < myFile.txt
```

or

```
sh Test.sh <<TESTCASES
433
434
434
TESTCASES
```

Comment: edited my code to something working now, can you please advice for failure cases

Comment: Don't make major changes to your question after it has been answered. Open a new question.

Comment: i dint understand the second option clearly, would you please explain..Thanks